# How to use Convolution2D in keras?

Tags: python, keras

What kinds of parameters should I use for convolution2D in keras?

```
    self.model.add(Convolution2D(32, 3, 3, border_mode='same', input_shape=dataset.X_train.shape[1:]))
    self.model.add(Activation('relu'))
    self.model.add(Convolution2D(32, 3, 3))
    self.model.add(Activation('relu'))
    self.model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
    self.model.add(Dropout(0.25))
```

Comment: You need to check the version of Keras you're using then check the documentation for that version. Or at least edit your question and add this information so I (or others) can check the documentation for you! When you will edit your question, please tell us also what 32, 3, 3 should be in your opinion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use Convolution2D in Keras, you typically need to specify a few key parameters:

- **Number of Filters** (e.g., 32): This represents the number of output
  filters in the convolution.
- **Kernel Size** (e.g., 3x3): The dimensions of the convolution window.
  In your code, it's specified as (3, 3).
- **Border Mode** (e.g., 'same'): This controls how the convolution
  handles borders. 'same' means the output size is the same as the
  input size. This is achieved by padding the input as necessary.
- **Input Shape** (e.g., input_shape=dataset.X_train.shape[1:]): This is
  required only for the first layer and specifies the shape of the
  input data.

In your example, you are creating a convolutional layer with **32 filters**, each with a **size of 3x3**. The border_mode is set to **'same'**, ensuring the output volume is the same size as the input. After the convolutional layer, you're adding an activation layer with the **ReLU function**. Then, you repeat these steps (minus the input shape specification, as it's only needed for the first layer). Following these, you add a **Max Pooling layer** to reduce the spatial dimensions, and a **Dropout layer** to prevent overfitting.

- **MaxPooling2D:**

  pool_size=(2, 2): This parameter specifies the size of the pooling
  window. Here, a 2x2 window is used. What this means is that for each
  2x2 area in the input feature map, the maximum value is taken and
  used to form a new, reduced feature map. Essentially, this operation
  reduces the spatial dimensions (height and width) of the input
  feature map by half, assuming the stride defaults to the pool size.
  Max pooling helps to reduce the computational load, memory usage, and
  also helps with reducing overfitting by providing an abstracted form
  of the representation.
- **Dropout:**

  0.25: This is the dropout rate. In this context, 0.25 means that during the training phase, each neuron (or connection) in the
  previous layer has a 25% chance of being temporarily "dropped out,"
  i.e., ignored during this training phase. This is a regularization
  technique used to prevent overfitting. By randomly dropping out
  neurons from the network during training, it ensures that the network
  does not become too reliant on any one neuron and thus can generalize
  better to new data.

This structure is quite standard for convolutional neural networks in image processing tasks. Remember, the specific values for filters, kernel size, and other parameters can vary depending on the specific task and dataset.